# Is there a linux program to make my keys clicky?

Tags: linux, keyboard, gnome, clicking-sound

In Windows, you can use the [ClicKey](http://www.grc.com/freeware/clickey.htm) program to make click sounds when you type keys. In Mac OS X, you can use [KeyClick](http://www.sustworks.com/site/prod_keyclick_overview.html).

Is there any such program for Linux? I'm using Gnome and Ubuntu 9.10. `xset c` doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't really answer the question, but I'm going to go out on a limb anyway and suggest that you invest in a quality, [buckling spring](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buckling_spring) keyboard.  That way, not only do you get the nice clicky-sound, but you get the robustness and "feel" that only come with that type of construction.

They are still being made, in beige and black, with and without "Windows" keys, and with USB connectors.  Google is your friend.

I use them daily on Windows and Linux machines, and have never had a problem.  I don't own a non-ADB Mac, so I can't say how they work there.

Happy clicking.

Comment: Heh - that's what I did a couple weeks ago. I had originally put this question up to try to figure out if I would like a buckling-spring keyboard!

Comment: Too funny; I learned to type on an IBM Selectric, and so have always loved the buckling-spring feel.  When I found I could still get one, especially since I was working as a coder at the time, I bought a few.  The only thing I use "modern" keyboards for, now, are FPS video games.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the Gnome [Accessibility options](http://library.gnome.org/users/user-guide/stable/prefs-keyboard.html.en). Read the section on "Keyboard Accessibility Audio Feedback"

Comment: I did, but on the real system, those checkboxes are grayed out.

Comment: I got them enabled by turning on Slow Keys, but there's still no sound.

Comment: Do you have a non-Pulse driver you can use?  Sometimes the older (alsa, analog, etc) work when pulse gives trouble.

Answer (score 0):

OK... buyer beware; this is a total guess.

Try this:

- add yourself to the 'pulse_access' group
- log out and back in
- see if xset c works then

I can't get keyclick working either (i.e. xset c 100 didn't work for me either) and I wanted to share this before trying steps 2 and 3 above.

Hope this helps (us both!)
-pbr

EDIT: http://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/PulseAudio leads me to believe it's the pulse_access group not the audio group; additional steps may be needed as well.  The switch to pulseaudio seems to have introduced a few wrinkles, huh?

Comment: Tell me about it. Pulseaudio has been a huge headache for me for a while! I keep hoping I'll find that the next release will have pulseaudio-enabled everything, and that never is the case.

Comment: That didn't seem to help, though the group is called `pulse-access`, not `pulse_access`.